# Subversion MultiSite read-only directory cannot be used as the source of a Subversion copy?

Tags: svn

My team is using Subversion with Wandisco's "MultiSite" product.   We just finished the release of our 6.0 product, and I have asked our DevOps team to make the 'branches/6.0' branch read-only, so that no further work be done on it.  My plan was to do a 'svn copy /branches/6.0 /branches/6.0.1' where 6.0.1 development work will be done...but I get a 'Access to  forbidden' error.

This seems strange to me that the *source* of a subversion copy must be read/write?  Does anyone know of a workaround, either in terms of the svn copy command or in terms of a status we can set in MultiSite?

Comment: Are you sure that DevOps set ReadOnly rule on /branches/6.0? There is a chance that they put ReadOnly to /branches and you can't add any branches anymore. BTW, do you use Access Control Plus from Wandisco? If you do, it could be that the root cause is in this product. Therefore, you could try contacting the support team of Wandisco.